# How to override the nested array object

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, object

I would like to know how to overwrite the values in an object array if exists else merge the objects using Javascript.

For example, `targetAmount` matches in parent, so I need to override the matched value and remaining values just insert the parent object.

```js
var my_obj = [{
  description: "transferwise_description"
  fee: "0.5"
  id: "transferwise"
  logo: "transferwiselogo.png"
  name: "Transferwise"
  speed: "1 Days"
  targetAmount: "2000"
}]

var tomerge_obj = {
  rate: 51.00674
  source: "SGD"
  sourceAmount: 1000
  target: "INR"
  targetAmount: 50688.97
  type: "REGULAR"
}
```

Expected Output

```
var merged_object = [{
  description: "transferwise_description"
  fee: "0.5"
  id: "transferwise"
  logo: "transferwiselogo.png"
  name: "Transferwise"
  speed: "1 Days"
  rate: 51.00674
  source: "SGD"
  sourceAmount: 1000
  target: "INR"
  targetAmount: 50688.97
  type: "REGULAR"
}]
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: And if *what* exists?

Comment: [`Object.assign()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in one line with `Object.assign()`. You can find more documentation on it [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign).

```
const result = Object.assign({}, my_obj[0], tomerge_obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can simply use [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), this way:

```
var merged_object = {...my_obj[0], ...tomerge_obj}
```

It will return a new object with the values from `tomerge_obj` duplicated keys will replace the ones in the object inside `my_obj`.

You can also use `Object.assign` and assign both objects to an empty one to achieve the same result.

Answer (score 0):

```
  var my_obj = [{
  description: "transferwise_description",
  fee: "0.5",
  id: "transferwise",
  logo: "transferwiselogo.png",
  name: "Transferwise",
  speed: "1 Days",
  targetAmount: "2000"
}];

var tomerge_obj = {
  rate: 51.00674,
  source: "SGD",
  sourceAmount: 1000,
  target: "INR",
  targetAmount: 50688.97,
  type: "REGULAR"
};

my_obj[0] = {...my_obj[0], ...tomerge_obj};
console.log(my_obj);
```

---

```
 my_obj[0] = {...my_obj[0], ...tomerge_obj};
```

'...' is the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_syntax) and is commonly used for object de-structuring.

---

What this will essentially do is that it will reassign the first element of the array with the newly created object by spreading the attributes of the two objects.

The console.log will prove the assertion.

Answer (score -1):

jQuery's `extend` is here just for that (answered this because you tagged jQuery, it has a much wider browser support than `assign` or spread operator)

Note that it modifies the original object, if you don't want, use `var res = $.extend(true, {}, my_obj[0], tomerge_obj);`

```js
var my_obj= [
  {
    description: "transferwise_description",
    fee: "0.5",
    id: "transferwise",
    logo: "transferwiselogo.png",
    name: "Transferwise",
    speed: "1 Days",
    targetAmount: "2000",
  }
];

var tomerge_obj = {
  rate: 51.00674,
  source: "SGD",
  sourceAmount: 1000,
  target: "INR",
  targetAmount: 50688.97,
  type: "REGULAR",
};

$.extend(true, my_obj[0], tomerge_obj)

console.log(my_obj);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```